# How to prove the distributivity of Cartesian products over unions and intersections

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$
\prod \limits_{i \in I} \left(\bigcup \limits_{j \in J_{i}} A_{i,j}\right)
=
\bigcup_{j \in \prod \limits_{i \in I } J_{i} }\left(\prod \limits_{i \in I}  A_{i,j(i)}\right)
$$

$$
\prod \limits_{i \in I} \left(\bigcap \limits_{j \in J_{i}} A_{i,j}\right)
=
\bigcap_{j \in \prod \limits_{i \in I } J_{i} }\left(\prod \limits_{i \in I}  A_{i,j(i)}\right)
$$

Here
$\prod$ means Cartesian product; 
$I$ and $J_{i}$ are the index sets. $A_{i,j}$ is set; and the meaning of $j(i)$ is,  for example, if $j=(1,3,4,5)$, then $j(4)=5$

For example: when $I=\{1,2\}$, we have 
$$
\bigcup \limits_{j \in J} A_{j} \times \bigcup \limits_{k \in K} B_{k}= \bigcup \limits_{k \in K } \bigcup \limits_{j \in J }(A_{j} \times B_{k})
$$

$$
\bigcap \limits_{j \in J} A_{j} \times \bigcap \limits_{k \in K} B_{k}= \bigcap \limits_{k \in K } \bigcap \limits_{j \in J }(A_{j} \times B_{k})
$$

Comment: When $I \subset \mathbb{N}$ , it is easy, you can use mathematical induction. But how to proof it when $|I|>=|\mathbb{N}|$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am gonna provide you with a down to earth proof of the equality (the other one can be obtained along the same lines):
$$
\prod \limits_{i \in I} \left(\bigcup \limits_{j \in J_{i}} A_{i,j}\right)
=
\bigcup_{j \in \prod \limits_{i \in I } J_{i} }\left(\prod \limits_{i \in I}  A_{i,j(i)}\right)$$

Starting with the inclusion "$\subseteq$", pick $x\in\prod \limits_{i \in I} \left(\bigcup \limits_{j \in J_{i}} A_{i,j}\right)$.

By definition of the product, I can write $x$ as $x=(x_i)_{i\in I}$ such that for each $i$, $x_i\in\bigcup \limits_{j \in J_{i}} A_{i,j}$.

Then for each $i\in I$, there exists a $j_i\in J_i$ such that $x_i\in A_{i,j_i}$, by definition of the union. Assuming some choice, pick such a $j_i$ for each $i$ and call $j = (j_i)_{i\in I}$.

Now it should be clear that $x\in \bigcup_{j \in \prod \limits_{i \in I } J_{i} }\left(\prod \limits_{i \in I}  A_{i,j(i)}\right) $, since for each $i\in I$, $x_i\in A_{i,j_i}$. And so $$x=(x_i)_{i\in I}\in\prod \limits_{i \in I}  A_{i,j_i}\subseteq\bigcup_{j \in \prod \limits_{i \in I } J_{i} }\left(\prod \limits_{i \in I}  A_{i,j(i)}\right).$$

You can prove the reverse inclusion as follows. Pick and $x \in\bigcup_{j \in \prod \limits_{i \in I } J_{i} }\left(\prod \limits_{i \in I}  A_{i,j(i)}\right)$.

Unfolding the definition of the union, you get that there exists a $j = (j_i)_{i\in I}\in \prod_{i \in I } J_{i} $ such that $x\in\left(\prod \limits_{i \in I}  A_{i,j_i}\right)$. But unfolding the definition of a product now, it means that for each $i\in I$, there exists an $x_{j_i}\in A_{i,j_i} \subseteq \bigcup \limits_{j \in J_{i}} A_{i,j}$ such that $x=(x_{j_i})_{i\in I}$. But it precisely means that $x=(x_{j_i})_{i\in I}\in\prod \limits_{i \in I} \left(\bigcup \limits_{j \in J_{i}} A_{i,j}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

A member of the Cartesian product $\prod_{i \in I}\left( \bigcup_{j \in J_i} A_{i,j}\right)$ is just a function $f$ with domain $I$ such that for each $i \in I$, $f(i) \in \bigcup_{j \in J_i} A_{i,j}$. So for each $i \in I$ pick (we use the Axiom of Choice here) some $g(i) \in J_i$ such that $f(i) \in A_{i, g(i)}$, AC then tells us we have a function $g \in \prod_{j \in I} J_i$ and by construction $f$ is in $\prod_{i \in I} A_{i, g(i)}$, and $f$ is in the right hand side.

The reverse inclusion is straightforward and does not depend on AC.

The second identity is simpler and follows straight from the definitions of Cartesian products (as sets of functions) and intersections.